# PostGraphile: One-To-Many relationships

Tags: postgraphile

I inherited a database structure which works like this: I have two tables, one for `Appointment`s and one for `Visit`s. When someone makes an `Appointment`, they can describe certain `Problem`s (a third table) to be addressed during a `Visit`. An `Appointment` can be converted into a `Visit` and carries over all of its `Problem`s (and depending on the user's setup may always preserve the `Appointment`, always delete the `Appointment`, or user's choice).

Besides an internal primary key, Problem also has an external key which refers back to the primary key of either `Appointment` or `Visit`. There's a secondary field indicating which table the key refers to. Looking at existing code, it seems like `Problems` are converted by changing both the key and the secondary field from `Appointment` to `Visit`.

Now, if I put a constraint on `Problem` such that its external key must reference `Appointment`, Postgraphile will give me the option of pulling `problemsByAppointmentKey` with an `Appointment` and if I force it to reference `Visit`, it will give me the option of pulling `problemsByVisitKey` when I pull a `Visit`.

As far as I can tell, I can't force `Problem`s to reference both tables. I can make a custom query to pull the problems for one or the other, but that's another call in addition to the one for `Visit` and `Appointment`. Also, it is kind of nice to have the entire `Visit` or `Appointment` returned in a single structure. (Also, there's another table `Recommendation` that's set up exactly the same way as `Problem`.)

Is there a way to describe this in PG in such a way that Postgraphile will pick it up and make the nested object calls like it does with a foreign-key constraint? I can also, at least theoretically, radically change the DB, though the more radical the changes, the harder the conversion process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are saying that refactoring your tables may be problematic due to some legacy logic. So I think the simplest solution would be to add [generated columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) for `appointment_id` and `visit_id` with relevant foreign keys on those columns.

So assuming your schema looks something like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ex_schema.appointments(
    id bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    scheduled_for timestamptz NOT NULL,
    is_cancelled boolean NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ex_schema.visits(
    id bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    start_time timestamptz NOT NULL,
    end_time timestamptz NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ex_schema.problems(
    id bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    ref_id bigint NOT NULL,
    ref_type varchar(63) check ( ref_type in ('VISIT','APPOINTMENT') ),
    UNIQUE (ref_id,ref_type)
);
```

you can run:

```sql
ALTER TABLE ex_schema.problems
    ADD COLUMN visit_id bigint generated always as ( case when ref_type = 'VISIT' then ref_id else null end ) STORED REFERENCES ex_schema.visits UNIQUE ,
    ADD COLUMN appointment_id bigint generated always as ( case when ref_type = 'APPOINTMENT' then ref_id else null end ) STORED REFERENCES ex_schema.appointments UNIQUE;
```

Postgraphile will immediately pick up the appropriate relationships. Since the new columns are generated, no triggers or legacy application logic should break due to their addition.